# Manipulating File to create Classifier Training and Test Data

Tags: list-manipulation, import, files-and-directories

I am reading a file

```
test = ReadList["https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data", {Record, Record, Record, Record, Record, Record, Record, Record, Record}, 768,  RecordSeparators -> {",", "\n", "\r", "\r\n"}]
```

I want to get that data in the following format (I only show a snippet)

```
data = {{6, 148, 72, 35, 0, 33.6, 0.627, 50} -> 1, 
        {1, 85, 66, 29, 0, 26.6, 0.351, 31} -> 0, 
        {8, 183, 64, 0, 0, 23.3, 0.672, 32} -> 1, 
        {1, 89, 66, 23, 94, 28.1, 0.167, 21} -> 0, 
        {0, 137, 40, 35, 168, 43.1, 2.288, 33} -> 1}
```

I was able to use the following, but cannot seem to finish it to be like the above using

```
data1 = Table[Insert[test[[i]], "->", 9], {i, 1, Length[test]}]
```

Next, I would like to be able to select some number of those $768$ randomly, say $700$ of them in one list and then the other $68$ in another list. Is there a simple command that can do that (been searching, but no luck so far)?

The whole purpose for this is to put the data in a format to use the [*Classify*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the data as comma-separated values. [AssociationThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html) maps list items to the last element of each item, e.g., `{0, 84, 82, 31, 125, 38.2, 0.233, 23} -> 0`, which is saved as `datalist`.

[RandomSample](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample.html) makes a random list of 700 items chosen from the items in `datalist` that are taken as `trainingset`. Use [Complement](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) to make `exampleset`, which are the `datalist` items not chosen for `trainingset`.

```
data = Import[
   "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data", "CSV"];

datalist = Normal[AssociationThread[data[[All, 1 ;; -2]] -> data[[All, -1]]]];

select = RandomSample[Range[Length[data]], 700];
trainingset = datalist[[select]];
exampleset = datalist[[Complement[Range[Length[datalist]], select]]];
```